# Kdbg doesn't allow inspection of contents of std::string or std::vector

Tags: c++, ubuntu, kdbg

I'm using Kdbg as my debugging tool for routine purposes, but it doesn't appear to have any way to inspect the contents of a std::string or std::vector. This is a bit of a drawback as use of the standard library is definitely the Approved Way. Does anyone know how to make it do this, or does anyone know of a GUI debugger that does?

(Kdbg 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 10.4).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had time to look into this deeply, but this article on pretty printing using python in kdbg may be of help:   http://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/2010/08/make-debugging-easier-with-custom-pretty-printers/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, DarenW, but I think this is a bit of a strain for my pea-sized, so I won't be adopting it. I'll just print the contents the old-fashioned way.